# How to get CurrentCell location in DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

HI
How to get CurrentCell location in DataGridView. i need for when my load will load every comboboxes set above on datagridview current cell. and get same size. how can i do that?

Comment: What do you mean by *location*? The row and column numbers?

Comment: i mean column Location on Form

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the **zero-based *index* of the column** that contains the currently selected cell by using the **[`ColumnIndex` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.columnindex.aspx)** of the [`CurrentCell` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.currentcell.aspx):

```
if (myDataGridView.CurrentCell != null)
{
    int columnIndex = myDataGridView.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
}
```

Or, you can get the **column object *itself*** that contains the currently selected cell by using the **[`OwningColumn` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.owningcolumn.aspx)**:

```
if (myDataGridView.CurrentCell != null)
{
    DataGridViewColumn columnObject = myDataGridView.CurrentCell.OwningColumn;
}
```

Note that I'm still not entirely sure if this is what you're asking for. My *forms* don't have columns, so I'm assuming that you mean the `DataGridView`. And your answer still doesn't really explain what exactly you mean by "location," but this should tell you everything you need to know about the column that contains the current cell.